# e.preventDefault() not letting me submit my form

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, preventdefault

I wrote some Javascript to validate a form.  However, if the form fields pass all validations, the form never submits!  Is my code somehow incorrectly preventing the form from being able to submit?  If I delete all of the Javascript and use browser's built-in validation then form executes fine and user is added to the database.

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');

const first_name = document.getElementById('first_name');
const last_name = document.getElementById('last_name');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const password2 = document.getElementById('password2');

// Show input error message
function showError(input, message) {
    input.className = 'form-control is-invalid';
    const small = input.parentElement.querySelector('small');
    small.className = 'invalid-feedback';
    small.innerText = message;
}

// Show success outline
function showSuccess(input, message) {
    input.className = 'form-control is-valid';
    const small = input.parentElement.querySelector('small');
    small.className = 'valid-feedback';
    small.innerText = message;
}


function checkRequired(inputArray) {
    inputArray.forEach(function(input) {
      if (input.value.trim() === '') {
        showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} is required`);
        return false;
      } else {
        showSuccess(input, "Looks Good!");
        return true;
      }
    });
}

// Check email is valid
function checkEmail(input) {
  const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if (re.test(input.value.trim())) {
    showSuccess(input, 'Looks Good!');
    return true;
  } else {
    showError(input, 'Email is not valid');
    return false;
  }
}

// Check input length
function checkLength(input, min, max) {
  if (input.value.length < min) {
    showError(
      input,
      `${getFieldName(input)} must be at least ${min} characters`
    );
    return false;
  } else if (input.value.length > max) {
    showError(
      input,
      `${getFieldName(input)} must be less than ${max} characters`
    );
    return false;
  } else {
    showSuccess(input, 'Looks Good!');
    return true;
  }
}

// Check passwords match
function checkPasswordsMatch(input1, input2) {
  if (input1.value !== input2.value) {
    showError(input2, 'Passwords do not match');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// Get fieldname
function getFieldName(input) {
  return input.id.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.id.slice(1);
}

// Event listeners
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

  if (!checkRequired([first_name, last_name, username, email, password, password2])) {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (!checkLength(username, 3, 15)) {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (!checkLength(password, 6, 25)) {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (!checkEmail(email)) {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (!checkPasswordsMatch(password, password2)) {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `checkRequired` function never returns anything at the moment:

```
function checkRequired(inputArray) {
    inputArray.forEach(function (input) {
        if (input.value.trim() === '') {
            showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} is required`);
            return false;
        } else {
            showSuccess(input, "Looks Good!");
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

You're returning inside the callback, but the callback ignores its return value (and you still wouldn't want to return `true` inside the loop, you'd only want to return `true` after all iterations have finished)

To find the first invalid input, use `.find`:

```
function checkRequired(inputArray) {
  const invalidInput = inputArray.find(input => input.value.trim() === '');
  if (invalidInput) {
    showError(input, `${getFieldName(invalidInput)} is required`);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

If you want to call `showError` for *every* invalid input, then:

```
function checkRequired(inputArray) {
  let valid = true;
  for (const input of inputArray) {
    if (input.value.trim() === '') {
      valid = false;
      showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} is required`);
    }
  }
  return valid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added show success as an else to the loop and also moved the checkRequired function to the last to execute in addEventListener to get the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: function checkRequired(inputArray) {
  let valid = true;
  for (const input of inputArray) {
    if (input.value.trim() === '') {
      valid = false;
      showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} is required`);
    }
    else {
        showSuccess(input, 'Looks Good!');
    }
  }
  return valid;
}

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from `checkRequired` so it's value will always be `false`. Although there should be no performance problems, you might be better off using a `for` loops so that you can break early.

```
function checkRequired(inputArray) {
    for (let input of inputArray) {
        if (input.value.trim() === '') {
            showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} is required`);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```